# Need help on timesheet submission reminder email

Tags: apex, community, force.com, salesforce2salesforce

Is there a way to have a reminder email sent out to users without using APEX/Batch processing but just with the help of configuration using Workflows/Approval Process?

1. It should send a reminder email if there is no time sheet created for the current week.
2. It should send a reminder email if a time sheet is created but not submitted by end of week.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No: you cannot create a workflow on the absence of a record
2. Yes: this is possible with time-based workflows

Give these two requirements, it may well be easier to either:

1. Create Apex logic to send out reminders and/or
2. Create Apex batch job to CREATE time sheets for all active users each week, and then use time-based workflows to manage reminders/escalations for those timesheets that are not submitted by the end of the week

Comment: You technically could for #1 by using roll up summaries and a count of the records and set the workflow criteria on the count = 0. (Although you cannot do the roll up on a weekly basis)

Comment: Interesting - could you set the rollup to just look at "this_week"? I can't test that right now but it might work ...

Comment: I think that you still CANNOT rollup based on dates or date functions unfortunately. (Unless something has changed). But you could have a daily batch run to mark a field true if it is for this week and use that field as part of the rollup.

Comment: Thank you, all! I will try with Roll Up and see if it works in anyways. 
However, I assume some sort of APEX coding is still needed here which is what I was trying to avoid.